# IPv6 - is the transition still urgent?

Tags: ipv4

Less than a decade ago there was a lot of talk about the urgency to get to IPv6 as the available routable IPv4 space was becoming quickly exhausted.   [Network World](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.networkworld.com/article/2196280/smartphones/mobility-drives-ipv6-urgency.amp.html)

Even with IPv4 essentially being [exhausted](https://www.networkworld.com/article/2985340/ipv6/arin-finally-runs-out-of-ipv4-addresses.html) there doesn’t appear to be the same sense of urgency as there was since there seems to be some alternate ways of getting an [IPv4 range](https://blog.apnic.net/2018/02/15/bad-ipv4-address-exhaustion/)

Have [IPv4 brokers](https://community.infoblox.com/t5/IPv6-CoE-Blog/IPv4-Address-Trading-for-Fun-and-Profit/ba-p/3496), cloud providers and [NAT translations](https://www.networkworld.com/article/2985340/ipv6/arin-finally-runs-out-of-ipv4-addresses.html) lessened the urgency?

Comment: Welcome Aaron.  Here at NE we very much like to focus on answerable problems like configuring machine X for task Y, and questions like this about attitudes and opinions, while interesting and important, are a bit off brief for us.  You might find the chat better suited.

Answer (score 3):

I think what we are seeing is a rethinking of what the IPv6 transition means and how it can feasibly be carried out.

A decade ago there was lots of talk, very little action.

The IPv6 proponents dream was that we would all move to dual-stack. Then once everything was dual-stacked IPv4 could be retired. The problem with that approach is it is really difficult to justify from a business perspective. You were increasing your network administration workload now in exchange for benefits that will only be realised at some unknown time in the future.

What we are starting to see now is companies thinking about how they can benefit from IPv6 without waiting for the whole world to transition. That is driving real large-scale deployments which in turn will increase the benefit side of the cost/benefit analysis for others.

On the exhaustion side we have seen what RIR exhaustion and IPv4 markets actually look like (rather than what people guessed they would look like). So-far prices have remained quite low which has possibly led some people to be less worried than they otherwise would be.

Reaching RIR exhaustion for normal allocations has also removed the perverse incentives inherent in the normal RIR allocation process (the more addresses you used the more you could get).